# AssertEquals doesn't stop test

Tags: java, selenium

Can anyone help me with AssertEquals?

I have the below code for my test case class, but after AssertEquals fails, the test continues to proceed to the next method i.e. createClientTodelete. Why?

```
public class Client

   {

public String baseUrl = "http://test.abc.com";
public WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeTest
  public void setBaseURL()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

  @Test(priority = 0, description = "verify successful login")
  public void verifyLogin()   
  {
String expectedDashTitle = "oms";
 String actualDashTitle = driver.getTitle();

Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.name("username")).size()>0);
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.name("password")).size()>0);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("admin");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("123@123");
driver.findElement(By.name("login")).submit();
Assert.assertEquals(actualDashTitle, expectedDashTitle,"Title Not Found!");
}


@Test(priority = 1, description = "verify client is created successfully")

  public void createClientTodelete()
  {

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mainMenu']/ul/li[2]/a/span")).click();  
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.linkText("Create")).size()>0);

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("company_name")).sendKeys("TestCompany");
    driver.findElement(By.id("contact_person_firstname")).sendKeys("FirstName");
    driver.findElement(By.id("contact_person_lastname")).sendKeys("LastName");
    driver.findElement(By.id("contact_person_email")).sendKeys("abc@test.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();
}
```

Comment: Because it is supposed to stop only the individual test with the failure, not the entire test suite.

Comment: If you use TestNG you can make one test depend on another by using the `dependsOnMethods` annotation parameter: `@Test(dependsOnMethods = "test1")`, `@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "test1", "test2" })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your code, its clear that you are using TestNG for these test.
In TestNG, you can use **"dependsOnMethods"** property as below.

```
package sample.testng;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.Assert;


public class SampleTest {

@Test
public void test(){
    System.out.println("Executing test 1");
    Assert.assertEquals("ABCD", "abc");
}


@Test(dependsOnMethods={"test"})
public void test1(){
    System.out.println("Second test runs only if the first one is successful, otherwise its ignored");
    //Asserts or whatever
}

}
```